# How can I change TableViewController datasource based on the user location

Tags: iphone, core-location

I am intended to do this 
I have a tab bar with 5 tab items and the first one is  hooked up to TableViewController
I would like the tableview datasource to be determined by the user location like city/state
I have this code in -ViewDidLoad

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = KCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = LCLLocationAccuracyHunderedMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and then getting the location in didUpdateToLocation and setting to the userCurrentLocation property.
But I can't get the userCurrentLocation to determine the datasource for the TableView.  Please advise.

Where to set the datasource like the below

```
if (userLocation == @"Sydney") 
{
arrData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"San Francisco",nil];
}
else
{
arrData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"California",nil];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to respond to the delegate method `didUpdateToLocations`, so I would recommend you to only start loading your tableview after this method is called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

That way you will guarantee you got an answer. See the delegate [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation) for further information.

Edit:

First you would have to set your class as the a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` you would do that in the header file of your class.

Although you would probably have to create your `UITableViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method though you would have to add your view controller tho the main view when the `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method is called.

If you need something else, let me know.

Comment: Thanks heaps. But can you please give an example of code snippet how can i load the table view which i am currently in after this method. Thanks in advance.